# Put image on different page relative to anchor

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an image that I want to fill an entire page with, but I also want to anchor it to some text in such a way that it always ends up on the next page. Is there a way to achieve this without placing it manually? I couldn't find anything useful in the Microsoft help regarding this.

Example: I have a few paragraphs, one of them containing the anchor, on page 3, the image is supposed to be on page 4. If I now add more paragraphs at the beginning of the document so that the text with the anchor moves to page 5, the image should move along to page 6.

Comment: What if you add a page break after the text and move the anchor to the top of the new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a page break after the text and put the anchor on top of the new page.

Comment: That would be a valid workaround. I had hoped to find a way to use the text wrap feature to start the new page automatically, though, as to not waste too much space for the page break.

Comment: What is the difference? A page break would take up more space than a text wrap feature, or?

Comment: Yes, i was hoping to save space, but it seems there is no better way to achieve that. Accepted.

Answer (score -1):

You likely want to put a picture on a blank page, do You ? Otherwise I cant see any sense of putting anchor to paragmaph on other page.
Wise heads say MS Word is a text processor, not a page editor. So it is unable to anchor the picture or an object to a blank page (as absolute position on page irrespective of text paragraph). It is anoying, frustrating and debilitating and critisized over many years by thousens of MS Word users writing booklets, books, adversiments and so on. There is less popular MS Publisher as DTP solution. Well, it would not be a bad choice if they would solve the compatibility issues with Word. If I opened Word processed illustrated book chapter in Publisher (to put a group of pictures on the page) it scrambled everything. So the choice of Ola is a workaround.  However, keep in mind such page break inserts so called first page, i.e. if You use headers and footers odd and even pages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Of course i could use a different program for creating my documents, and by now i do actually use a different solution. Nonetheless, your answer is not actually answering my question and should probably have been a comment instead.